# .NET Core 2 Password Hashing

Tags: hash, cryptography, .net-core-2.0

I am looking to hash a password in core 2. I would like to use something like bcrypt, however, I am struggling to find any core implementations.

Comment: It should be available through https://www.nuget.org/packages/BCrypt-Official/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try my nuget package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/BCrypt-Core/

```
Install-Package BCrypt-Core -Version 2.0.0
```